# How to use PHP DOMDocument saveHTML($node) without added whitespace?

Tags: php, domdocument

If I use `saveHTML()` without the optional `DOMnode` parameter it works as expected:

```
$html = '<html><body><div>123</div><div>456</div></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$dom->formatOutput = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

> ```
> <html><body><div>123</div><div>456</div></body></html>
> ```

But when I add a `DOMNode` parameter to *output a subset of the document* it seems to ignore the `formatOutput` property and adds a bunch of unwanted whitespace:

```
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
echo $dom->saveHTML($body);
```

> ```
> <body>
> <div>123</div>
> <div>456</div>
> </body>
> ```

What gives?  Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know your document is going to be valid XML as well, you can use `saveXML()` instead...

```
$html = '<html><body><div>123</div><div>456</div></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$dom->formatOutput = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
echo $dom->saveXML($body);
```

which gives...

```
<body><div>123</div><div>456</div></body>
```

Comment: Looking deeper into this, `saveXML()` respects the `formatOutput` property with or without the argument, while `saveHTML()` only works without argument.  Seems like a bug to me.  Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 5):

> Is this a bug?

Yes, it's a bug and it's reported [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76285)

> Is there a workaround?

Stick with Nigel's solution for now

> Did they fix it?

Yes, as of [7.3.0 alpha3](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.3.0alpha3/NEWS#L21) this is a fixed bug

Check it [here](https://3v4l.org/fcTVn)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a pretty ugly workaround, but it gets the job done:

```
$html = '<html><body><div>123</div><div>456</div></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$dom->formatOutput = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$dom->loadHTML(str_replace("\n", "", $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0))), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/418ce40cf6cd9a5408128356007da8f1b8cde88b)

Since `saveHTML()` returns the string, pass the Node to that, then replace the line breaks, then pass that to `loadHTML()`.

Comment: hehe - that is ugly but thanks.  at the moment I'm doing this: `str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)));` which I think yields the same result with a bit less effort.  I'm still looking for a better method but appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Okay.  In the future, if you already have a solution, but just don't like it, you should include that in your question.

Comment: Agreed Patrick, I actually posted the question before I came up with that workaround and was in the process of editing my question to make that clear when you posted this. That said, I've upvoted your answer and I think it's useful and you probably wouldn't have written it if I'd posted my workaround to begin with - alls well that ends well.

Comment: Yup.  I like Nigel's better anyway  :)